# PHPRedis and SMEMBERS

Tags: php, symfony, redis, phpredis

I'm trying some stuff with Redis and PHP, and I've encountered a problem when it came to work with `SETS` and `SMEMBERS`.

I'm using Symfony2 and `SncRedisBundle`.

```
$redis->multi();
// Some stuff
$result = $redis->smembers("myset");
var_dump($result);
die();
$redis->exec();
```

Here's the dump

```
object(Redis)[990]
  public 'socket' => resource(841, Redis Socket Buffer)
```

I'm a bit stuck now, I don't know how I can work with the result since there's nothing really visible or explained on php-redis documentation.

Can someone help me?

Comment: It seems to work fine when we remove the `MULTI .. EXEC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the result of $redis->exec() instead of the result of smembers. The principle of MULTI/EXEC blocks is that command executions are delayed until the EXEC command. At this point, all commands are executed atomically and their results are sent back to the client.

See this example: https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis#transactions

Note that using a MULTI/EXEC block with just one command inside is pointless and does not bring any benefits.